# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration. when using the Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova

Im currently using the Facebook Javascript SDK and I keep running into the following problem that appears in the console:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I've read a truck load of related posts but still can't get it to work. I am working locally using the following: `http://localhost:8080/bookbayapp/`. In my facebook developers app section I have the following:

[image]

But once again nothing seems to work. I am currently using Google Chrome for the testing and it is worth to mention that I am using the Facebook Plugin for Phonegap but when testing I comment out the link the to plugin js so I assume in doing this there shouldn't be any problems?

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is using the actual URL of the production server, and then adding a line to the hosts file that redirects all traffic from that URL to localhost.

Let's say your website is called potatoes.com. In "Site URL" write:

```
http://potatoes.com/bookbayapp
```

and then open your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and add the following line:

```
potatoes.com 127.0.0.1
```